# Vaadin 7 + Spring security configuration

Tags: spring, spring-security, vaadin

I'm trying to configure Spring Security + [Vaadin4Spring](https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring) together with my Vaadin 7 application.

I have following code:

`pom.xml` security related dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-vaadin-security</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

My `MainUI` class definition:

```
@VaadinUI
public class MainUI extends UI {
```

and `Application` class

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class Application extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN");
    }

}
```

Right now when I'm trying to access `http://localhost:8080/` I have following error message:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /error. Reason:Request was not handled by any registered handler.Powered by Jetty://
```

What I'm doing wrong ? Please help me, I'm stuck on this the second day Without Spring security my application works perfectly, but without security it's doesn't have a big sense.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved at the vaadin4spring github: https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/issues/78